# What's the best way to index this table

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HousePrices](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PropertyType] [int] NULL,
    [Town] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [County] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Outcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Price] [int] NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Which currently holds around 20 million records, and I need to run queries to calculate the average price in a certain area. For example:

```
select avg(price)
from   houseprices
where  town = 'London'
       and propertytype = 1
```

The WHERE clause could have any combination of Town, County or Outcode, and will probably always have PropertyType (which is one of four values). I've tried creating a non-clustered index on one of the fields, but that still took around 2 minutes to run.

Surely this should be able to run in under a second?

Comment: Google and learn about `Covering Index` and create an index that covers all the queries you might run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

- If your WHERE clause only returns a small subset of the records, then create an index *for each combination of search values*, e.g. one multi-field index on `PropertyType, Town, Country, Outcode`, another on `PropertyType, Country, Outcode`, etc. You can skip indexes which are prefixes of existing indexes (i.e. if you have an index `A, B, C, D`, you don't need `A, B, C`; however, you do need `A, C, D`, if `B` can be omitted).

  You can reduce the number of required indexes by reducing the number of combinations: For example, you could make `Country` mandatory when searching for `Town` -- which would make sense, since getting the average over Vienna (Austria) and Vienna (Virgina) would be quite useless.
- If your WHERE clause returns a large set of records, your query will take a lot of time anyway, since *all* the selected records need to be fetched from the HDD or cache to calculate the average. In this case, you can increase performance by including the `Price` column in your indexes as an [included column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx). This means that your query will only have to fetch the index rather than the actual rows.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to improve things quite a lot. I had include the price on the index.